# Android Error In Installing

Tags: android

I am developing an android app and I'm kinda stuck in between. I have completed the app but when I run the app on my phone it runs perfectly for the first time..but then after closing the app, it gets lost.

What i mean to say is that The app is not getting installed. But also, when I check my app settings, the app is present. But there is no sign of the app at home screen or whatsoever and there is no option to open the app. Any Idea anyone?

This is my manifest

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
```

```
<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
    <activity android:name=".AnagramsActivity">

    </activity>
    <activity android:name=".leader"/>

    <activity android:name=".LoginActivity">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            <data android:scheme="@string/fb_login_protocol_scheme" />
        </intent-filter>

    </activity>

    <activity android:name="com.facebook.FacebookActivity"
        android:configChanges=
            "keyboard|keyboardHidden|screenLayout|screenSize|orientation"
        android:label="@string/app_name" />

    <meta-data android:name="com.facebook.sdk.ApplicationId"
        android:value="@string/fb_app_id"/>
</application>

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
```

Comment: Did you try it on a different phone/emulator?

Comment: Also, are you using any Launcher?

Comment: have you set in `Manifest` some `ACTION-VIEW` for Firebase Indexing? Remove it and you have your icon in list of apps.

Comment: Can you post your manifest, please?

Comment: I can not understand what did I do wrong?